# PlatformException (PlatformException(Renderer already initialized, Renderer initialization called multiple times, null, null))

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps

I tried to use the latest map renderer for Google Maps Flutter, using this package [`google_maps_flutter_android: ^2.6.0`](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter_android#map-renderer)

here is my main function look like:

```
main() async {
  ...
  
  AndroidMapRenderer mapRenderer = AndroidMapRenderer.platformDefault;

  final GoogleMapsFlutterPlatform mapsImplementation =
    GoogleMapsFlutterPlatform.instance;
  if (mapsImplementation is GoogleMapsFlutterAndroid) {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    mapRenderer = await mapsImplementation.initializeWithRenderer(AndroidMapRenderer.latest);

  ...
  runApp(MyApp);
}
```

It works but since they mentioned

> The renderer must be requested before creating GoogleMap instances, as the renderer can be initialized only once per application context.

So whenever I tried to Hot Restart it return the `PlatformException (PlatformException(Renderer already initialized, Renderer initialization called multiple times, null, null))`

When I need to Hot Restart I need to comment that part of code.

Then I try using try catch for that part of code, but still it return the exception and pause the app.

The code is look something like this:

```
main() async {
  ...
  
  AndroidMapRenderer mapRenderer = AndroidMapRenderer.platformDefault;

  try {
    final GoogleMapsFlutterPlatform mapsImplementation =
      GoogleMapsFlutterPlatform.instance;
    if (mapsImplementation is GoogleMapsFlutterAndroid) {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
       mapRenderer = await mapsImplementation.initializeWithRenderer(AndroidMapRenderer.latest);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    log(e.toString());
  }

  ...
  runApp(MyApp);
}
```

Is there any way to run that part of code just once, even when Hot Reload it doesnt rerun that part of code ?

Comment: Ever since 18.2.0 of Maps SDK for Android was released, by default, apps built using version 18.2.0 of the Maps SDK for Android use the upgraded renderer. Though I'm not sure about the flutter library, but from what I know, as long as you are now using the latest version of the Maps SDK, you don't need to opt in anymore for the latest renderer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. But I wanted to use legacy renderer because of this bug https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/122401.

So, to "ignore" this error on hot restart, you can just don't call `await` on `mapsImplementation.initializeWithRenderer(AndroidMapRenderer.latest);`

It won't crash or stop your application in debug mode and will work in release (because it has no hot restart).

**Code:**

```
    final GoogleMapsFlutterPlatform mapsImplementation = GoogleMapsFlutterPlatform.instance;
    if (mapsImplementation is GoogleMapsFlutterAndroid) {
       WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
       mapsImplementation.initializeWithRenderer(AndroidMapRenderer.latest);
    }

    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
```

I think the problem persists because Google Maps plugin initializes renderer natively, but hot restart doesn't actually restart your app in Android and renderer stays initialized.